Why is the Greek word "egeneto" translated as "create" or "make" in John 1:3 and "became" in John 1:14 in some translations?
John 1:3 Douay-Rheims Bible
All things were made by him: and without him was made nothing that was made.
John 1:3 Christian Standard Bible
John 1:3 NET Bible
All things were created by him, and apart from him not one thing was created that has been created.
were made,
ἐγένετο (egeneto)
Verb - Aorist Indicative Middle - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 1096: A prolongation and middle voice form of a primary verb; to cause to be, i.e. to become, used with great latitude.
became
ἐγένετο (egeneto)
Verb - Aorist Indicative Middle - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 1096: A prolongation and middle voice form of a primary verb; to cause to be, i.e. to become, used with great latitude.
Does the word "egeneto" carry the meaning create out of nothing? Why is it translated inconsistently in John 1:3 and John 1:14?

... because it can mean all those things in various contexts.  However, whichever meaning is selected, it makes no difference to the overall meaning: Jesus was the originator of all things.

@Dottard. The Father has given life to Jesus. His life did not originate from himself.. John 5:26

... and thus you simply dismiss all the other Biblical data and select what suits your purpose?  That is cafeteria hermeneutics!

@Dottard.  I  find some of your answers and questions difficult to believe, thus I examine them. John 18:37, Jesus said he was born, but if Jesus is God how could that be true. I would be too naive and gullible to believe that the God of the Bible will say " I was born". It's good to examine what others say rather than blindly following. If you are100 percent certain of your answers and that there is no chink in your armor, then you can address any" flaws" that differing views may find with your answer instead of smugly calling it cafeteria hermeneutics.

That is what the Bible teaches.  The standard of faith is NOT what you find credible.  I do not understand the incarnation any more than anyone else - I accept it by faith alone.

@Dottard. I don't accept anything that I don't understand by faith alone. I know the God of the Bible is a God of reason. He will not ask us to reason together if he is not reasonable. You are free to make something that you do not understand as your standard of faith. If something has to be my standard of faith, then I have to understand it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Dottard. I comment and don't chat.

OK then.  Goodbye.

I would prefer: "All things came into being through him, and not one thing that came into being, came into being except through him".
By using a passive in English you are implying an agent - which may or may not be the case: "All things were created through him". So I would prefer to avoid it, but it's quite idiomatic. Mine is a bit wordy. ;)
Where there's a predicate, γίνομαι is usually translated "become".
"Word became flesh."
In 3rd person singular, it also commonly means "happen".
Ἐγένετο ἐν ταῖς ἡμέραις - It came about in those days...
It's not inconsistent, just versatile. Think about the meaning. Don't get hung up on the English.

If the words create and make are not included in the meaning of egeneto, what justifies these words being used in John 1:3?

@AlexBalilo πάντα δι᾽ αὐτοῦ ἐγένετο All things were made through him. Honestly, I don't like your translators for this reason. "Made by him" - by always implies a passive, ergo an agent, which in Greek is ὑπό + gen (as in John 14.21: ἀγαπηθήσεται ὑπὸ τοῦ πατρός μου - he will be loved BY my father. Once only; John avoids.)

I don't understand why you say " I don't like your translators" Whether a translation does imply or does not imply anything is a result of the translation. It is the meaning of the word egeneto that I am trying to examine as bible hub does not show that it carries the meaning "create or make". thus, why are they used? What idea do those that translate "egeneto" with create or make" are trying to imply in John 1:3?
